# MySQL UDF signal: controlar error en PHP

Tags: mysql, php7, funciones-mysql

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| razon_social        | varchar(50) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| fecha_alta          | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Y la siguiente función:

```
create function Nuevo_Cliente(rsocial varchar(50)) returns int
begin
    declare cant_err int;
    declare cant_rsocial int;
    declare mensaje longtext;

    
    set cant_err = 0;
    set cant_rsocial = -1;
    set mensaje = "";
    
    /* verificar la razón social */
    if ((rsocial is null) or (rsocial = "")) then
        set cant_err = cant_err + 1;
        set mensaje = concat(mensaje, "\n- La razón social no puede estar vacía");
         signal sqlstate '45001' set MESSAGE_TEXT = mensaje;
        return 1;
    else
        select count(id) into cant_rsocial from clientes where razon_social = rsocial;
        if (cant_rsocial != 0) then
            set cant_err = cant_err + 1;
            if (cant_rsocial > 0) then
                set mensaje = concat(mensaje, "\n- La razón social ya existe");
                 signal sqlstate '45002' set MESSAGE_TEXT = mensaje;
                return 2;
            else
                set mensaje = concat(mensaje, "\n- La razón social no se puede verificar");
                 signal sqlstate '45003' set MESSAGE_TEXT = mensaje;
                return 3;
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
    
    insert into clientes (razon_social, fecha_alta) values (rsocial, now());
    return 0;
end //
```

La función funciona como se espera. Ahora el problema lo tengo cuando intento controlar el error en PHP:

```
$consulta = "select Nuevo_Cliente('Razón Social')";
if ($mysql->consulta($consulta) === false) {echo "<pre>error " . $mysql->errno . ": ". $mysql->err . "</pre>";}
else echo "<pre>alta correcta</pre>";
```

Si el alta NO es correcta recibo un warning. Por ejemplo, en esta prueba:

```
Warning: mysqli::query(): (45002/1644): - La razón social ya existe in /ruta/cDb.php on line 57
```

Y si que puedo mostrar el mensaje de error generado por la función de MySQL en PHP:

```
error 1644: 
- La razón social ya existe
```

Lo que quiero es evitar que se muestre ningún warning o error o excepción ya que para eso estoy intentando manejarlo en MySQL.

Gracias!

Comment: Has probado a encerrarlo entre un try/catch y manejar la excepción que te da?

Comment: El mensaje se muestra, porque lo estás mostrando: `if ($mysql->consulta($consulta) === false) {echo "<pre>error " . $mysql->errno . ": ". $mysql->err . "</pre>";}` Si no quieres mostrarlo, quita esto: `echo "<pre>error " . $mysql->errno . ": ". $mysql->err . "</pre>";`, de todos modos, no es bueno tener un código mudo en caso de error. Puedes responder con un array, en el cual pones una clave `error` y en caso de error activar tu política de errores, donde muestres un mensaje personalizado, o donde decidas qué hacer en caso de error.

Comment: El warning lo recibo desde la clase cDB, independientemente de si muestro el error o no, el warning se recibe y "no debería ser" ya que para eso hago `if ($mysql->consulta($consulta) === false)`. Además el código `45002 - la razón social ya existe` lo emito yo desde MySQL: `if (cant_rsocial > 0) then
                set mensaje = concat(mensaje, "\n- La razón social ya existe");
                 signal sqlstate '45002' set MESSAGE_TEXT = mensaje;
                return 2;
            else...`. La idea es desde MySQL lanzar el error, ya que es un error, no un warning.

Comment: He declarado el sgte `error handler`: `declare exit handler for sqlexception return err_code;` y en los bloques `if` he añadido `set err_code = #` y he comentado los `signal...`. De esta manera el warning no se lanza. Pero ahora en PHP recibo un array de la sgte manera: `Array ( [Nuevo_Cliente('Razón Social')] => 2 )`. Debería recibir un simple código de error.

Comment: *El warning lo recibo desde la clase cDB*. ¿Eso qué es, un archivo `.php`?, pues entonces pulsa en [edit] y muéstranos ese archivo. Como ya te dije, si pones un `echo` con un mensaje de error, tendrás un mensaje de error. Igualmente, si no silencias los errores en PHP, tendrás mensajes de error o advertencias, según la configuración que hayas indicado en tu entorno PHP. Dinos entonces cuál es tu configuración PHP al respecto.

Comment: No es la clase cDb. Funciona según lo esperado y la estoy usando en otros proyectos. He resuelto el warning añadiendo el `exit handler` para cada error: `declare exit handler for sqlstate '4500#' return #;` disparado por `signal sqlstate '4500#' set MESSAGE_TEXT = mensaje;`. Pero no puedo conseguir tener un nro de error y un mensaje de error. Obtengo un array y no algo como  `if ($mysql->consulta($consulta) === false)...`

Comment: Y ni siquiera es un array asociativo del tipo `[nro_error] => 'descripcion'`. Es así: `Nuevo_Cliente('Razón Social xx', 'razon social'): 5`.